# UDPROS/TCPROS - how to select?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I was talking with a friend about ROS and he said me that have had some problems (latency) on communicating nodes using a wireless communication. Reading [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Topics) I saw that TCP is the default transport used in ROS.

In fact if you are working with wireless communication and use TCP for that you can have some problems because the "nature" of the protocol itself.

*So the question is*: How do I select/change to UDPROS? Is that choice "global" (affect all topics)?
:D

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10200/udpros/tcpros---how-to-select?/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-06-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are looking for: [Transport Hints](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1TransportHints.html).
It should only be for one topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-10-21**:
Some of the subscribe() variants let you pass a TransportHints, but how do you use that on the publisher end?